# SQL Server : trigger handle multiple rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a trigger if I do multiple insert then I get an error on:

```
IF((SELECT FACTREGELPRIJS FROM inserted) > 0)
```

This is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg]
ON [dbo].[FACTUURREGEL]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @rowCount INT = @@ROWCOUNT 

    IF(@rowCount = 0)
        RETURN

    BEGIN TRY
        IF(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inserted) 
           AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM deleted))
        BEGIN
            IF((SELECT FACTREGELPRIJS FROM inserted) > 0)
            BEGIN
                RAISERROR('MAG geen prijs toegevoegd worden',16,1)
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                UPDATE f 
                SET FACTREGELPRIJS = (p.PRODUCTPRIJS * f.FACTREGELHOEVEELHEID) - ((p.PRODUCTPRIJS * f.FACTREGELHOEVEELHEID)*(f.FACTREGELKORTING/100.0))
                FROM FACTUURREGEL f
                INNER JOIN PRODUCT p on p.PRODUCTID = f.PRODUCTID
            END
        END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

        DECLARE
            @ErrorMessage   VARCHAR(400),
            @ErrorSeverity  INT,
            @ErrorState     INT

        SELECT
            @ErrorMessage   = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
            @ErrorSeverity  = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
            @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE()

        RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage , @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState)
    END CATCH
END
```

How can I fix it? thank you

Comment: You need to use aggregate(`max(...)`) for `if` condition and you have to join to `inserted` pseudo-table to perform updates. Remember that triggers are fired for entire set of changes, not for every record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare a column with a scalar value. Your query should return a scalar value not a column.

For example something like this:

```
IF((SELECT count(FACTREGELPRIJS) FROM inserted)> 0)
```

For checking price do this:

```
IF((SELECT SUM(FACTREGELPRIJS) FROM inserted)> 0)
```

Comment: What are you checking in if statement ?

Comment: I can't instert invoice price, if price > 0 error,

The price is based on quantity, price and discount

Comment: so you are checking if any row was inserted or not. Am i right?

Comment: Each row is a new invoice.
should column "price" are checked. Which should not be greater than 0

Comment: i need a check every insert row, 
not all inserted rows together

Comment: SQL server doesn't support row level trigger. You have to check for all rows together.

Comment: perhaps I did not properly explained.

I do INSER INTO TABLE (example_id, name, price)
VALUES
  (100, 'Name 1',3'),
  (101, 'Name 2', 0)

then i have 2 rows in inserted.
Can i check per row in inserted?